# Should [modal-dialog] be renamed to [modal-window]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

When reading [Is a lightbox considered a dialog box?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/26358/is-a-lightbox-considered-a-dialog-box) (and writing my answer) I realized our tag for "modal" stuff is [modal-dialog](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modal-dialog). As you'll note in my answer, I don't agree that all modal things are dialogs; instead there are [dialog](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialog) (an existing tag) and there are [modal-windows](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modal-windows).

Modality is a different issue from dialog-ness. Dialogs can be non-modal, and not all modal interaction elements fit the classic "Alert: yes/no" format of the traditional dialog. In my opinion we should keep the ideas distinct and just tag [dialog](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialog) and [modal-windows](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modal-windows) separately.

Should we rename the [modal-dialog](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modal-dialog) that to [modal-windows](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modal-windows)? I added the pluralization since it seems like we prefer plural noun tags.

Comment: Presumably we'd then have to retag the ones which were actually talking about [tag:dialog]? Can't imagine it will take very long, but worth noting.

Comment: A lot of people refer to these as modal-dialogs though. I would use both

Comment: @mattrockwell Even if people refer to them as modal-dialogs, should we not promote correct usage of terminology here?

Comment: But you can have modal dialogs as well as modal windows. Would adding "modal" tag be better?

Comment: @norabora just [tag:modal] to cover both cases would be fine with me. I don't think there's any relevant distinction between the two that isn't covered by adding the [tag:dialog] tag separately where needed

Answer (score 1):

I recently asked a question regarding what I consider "modal dialogs".

[Is there any definitive research on modal/overlay forms? Specifically, dismissing behaviors](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/48437/is-there-any-definitive-research-on-modal-overlay-forms-specifically-dismissin)

I didn't get a good answer because it seems people have different notions of what a modal dialog box is.

You can see from my language, I labored on what to call it.

When I think of modal dialog box, I think of the classic Action/Cancel popups from the application era. However I don't know what the agreed upon name is for all the modern web and mobile iterations we see today.

However, I DO believe I meant modal-window or window-overlay[-box].

To me, a modal-window is the combination of an overlay covering the entire window   with a new smaller interface window embedded in it demanding user action. I am not sure if a modal-dialog implies all the same features.

When I search wikipedia for modal dialog, modal **window** returns as the result

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_dialog

They also mention lightbox. But that has distinct implementations and is an additional tag in my opinion.

If I had a vote, I would say it's good to change modal-dialog to modal-window

Comment: Since this got to +10 with only minor opposition and two answers in supprt I've made the tags synonyms, and modal-windows will show on questions for now. It's easy to reverse or make additional tags if we decide that's necessary